# OkHttp 2.0 manually verifying cipher suite in use

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am trying to work out a way to check the Cipher Suite (CS) that has been chosen during the TLS handshake. I want to be able to manually kick out of the handshake, or at least stop the body of the http message being sent if the CS fails some manual check.

I am requesting a subset of CSs using a custom `SocketFactory` but this is not always honoured by the server.

I have played with doing this inside the `HandshakeCompletedListener` callback but this is proving difficult. Throwing any `RuntimeException` class will not do anything due to the catch all in the calling method. Closing the socket wont make any difference either, which i thought may internally throw an exception, which would not be a great solution anyway.

Any help would be great.

*EDIT*: after @jesse-wilsons answer below I am using 2.1-RC1 and the `ConnectionSpec` class to specify what Cipher Suites (CS) I want to use - however there are cases when an existing SSL session can be reused with a differnt cipher suite. I have included a custom HostNameVerifier to catch any cases where an SSL connection is trying to be setup with a differnt than requested CS. This is a little bit of a shoehorn but I cant see another way to hook in after the SSL handshake has taken place.

```
public class HostnameAndCipherSuiteVerifier implements HostnameVerifier
{
    private final String mHostname, mCipherSuite;

    public HostnameAndCipherSuiteVerifier(String hostname, String cipherSuite)
    {
        mHostname = hostname;
        mCipherSuite = cipherSuite;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
    {
        //delegate to original hostname verifier
        if(!OkHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE.verify(hostname, session))
        {
            XLog.w("delegate hostname check failed");
            return false;
        }

        //hardcode check for domain
        if(!hostname.equals(mHostname))
        {
            XLog.w("Hard-coding hostname fail");
            return false;
        }

        //handshake cipher check
        if(!session.getCipherSuite().equals(mCipherSuite))
        {
            XLog.w("cipher check failed");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab OkHttp 2.1-RC1 and use the new ConnectionSpec class to limit the cipher suites to those you like.

Comment: Thats cool thanks - nicer way to specify the requested CS. However this __does not__ ensure that only these CS are accepted. Will update my answer above with the current solution I am using to force CS selection - would be great if you can tell me if there is an easier way or if the above approach will cause any issues. Thanks :)